# Discord.JS data.some is not a function when checking message.content against array

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

I'm trying to check message.content against a JSON and an API link that is fetched and stored to the const `data` for a automod bot.

The JSON and API link both contain arrays with 600+ items stored.

The idea is to check against a locally stored JSON, and then an API to prevent links being posted.

The code works fine for 90% of the time, but while testing and sending multiple links in a short space of time, i get this error:

> TypeError: data.some is not a function

This is the code:

```
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
     try {
          const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(message.guildId);
          const member = guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id);
          const modLogs = client.channels.cache.get(modLogsChannelID);
          const response = await fetch(
               definedAPI,
          );
          const data = await response.json();

          if (badLinksJSON.some(letter => message.content.includes(letter))) {
               console.log(`${member.user.tag} used a bad link and has been muted.`)
               member.roles.add(mutedRoleID).catch(err => console.error);
               message.channel.send(`${message.author.toString()} You have been muted for: **Bad Link Usage**`).catch(console.error).then(message.delete()).catch(err => console.error);

          } else if (data.some(word => message.content.includes(word))) {
               console.log(`${member.user.tag} used a bad link and has been muted.`)
               member.roles.add(mutedRoleID).catch(err => console.error);
               message.channel.send(`${message.author.toString()} You have been muted for: **Bad Link Usage**`).catch(console.error).then(message.delete()).catch(err => console.error);
          }  
     } catch (error) {
          message.channel.send('Oops, there was an error fetching the API');
          console.log(error);
     }
}
```

*Note: > Multiple variables are defined in the code file above, I have not included them in the code snippet*

The try and catch were added to prevent the bot from crashing if this error occured. I am aware it could be done other ways.

Any help is appreciated, TIA.

Comment: Wait, if you just have to see if the message contains links why don't just use a simple regex?

Comment: Not all links need to be deleted, only certain ones that are listed in the API or JSON. E.G, if i wanted to block youtube.com links i could add it to the json, but google.com links would still be allowed.

Comment: What returns `response.json()` when the code throws this error? Have you logged it?

Comment: When i console.log(data), which is response.json. It shows exactly the same if the error happens as it does working normally, it just shows the array.

Since it only happens when multiple messages are sent within a short space of time (to the point where the bot gets rate limited), i'm not that worried that it throws the error. 
The only time I can see this being an issue is if the guild gets raided by multiple bots/users posting at the same time.

Comment: your APIs have maybe a rate limit, if you make a call on every request it's pretty common i would say